# How to partially specialize a factory struct for all `std::array`s with more than `4` elements?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, template-specialization

I want to dispatch a call from factory function template to a struct that is partially specialized based on the return type:

```
#include <array>

template<typename Type, typename Enable=void> 
struct make_it; 

template<typename A> 
struct make_it<std::array<A, 3>>
{
    static std::array<A, 3> apply()
    {
        return {A{0}, A{1}, A{2}}; 
    }
};

template<typename A> 
struct make_it<std::array<A, 4>>
{
    static std::array<A, 4> apply()
    {
        return {A{0}, A{0}, A{0}, A{0}}; 
    }
};

template<typename T> 
constexpr bool greater(T&& a, T&& b)
{
    return a > b;
}

template<typename T, int N> 
struct make_it<std::array<T, N>, std::enable_if_t<greater(N,4)>>
{
    static std::array<T, N> apply()
    {
        return std::array<T,N>{};  
    }
};

template<typename Type> 
Type make()
{
    return make_it<Type>::apply(); 
}

int main()
{
    auto a = make<std::array<double,3>>(); 
    auto b = make<std::array<double,4>>(); 
    auto c = make<std::array<double,5>>();
}
```

Compiled with

```
g++  -O3 -std=c++2a -Wall -Wpedantic -Wunused-parameter -I /usr/include main.cpp -o main
```

using `g++ (GCC) 8.2.1 20181127` this results in an error

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Type make() [with Type = std::array<double, 5>]’:
main.cpp:49:41:   required from here
main.cpp:42:32: error: incomplete type ‘make_it<std::array<double, 5>, void>’ used in nested name specifier
     return make_it<Type>::apply();
```

Is there something wrong with the SFINAE line

```
struct make_it<std::array<T, N>, std::enable_if_t<greater(N,4)>>
```

I figured this should partially specialize `make_it`, enable the tempplate for all `N > 4`. So if `N == 5`, this template becomes "visible", and it surely fits better to the call

```
auto c = make<std::array<double,5>>();
```

than an incomplete type? What is happening here?

Comment: I guess you're using `greater` because `<N > 4>` confuses the parser, but you can use `<(N > 4)>` instead.

Comment: @Quentin: thanks this gets rid of `greater` but the error is still there.

Comment: Note that [Clang compiles this fine](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UigxdQ8Lag9Rjoby). This might require a language lawyer!

Comment: @Quentin: OK, thanks!

Comment: I believe this can be simplified to `template<class> struct A; template<class T, int N> struct A<std::array<T, N>> {}; A<std::array<int, 4>> a;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know who's right (g++ that gives error or clang++ that compiles) but I see that in your code there is an imperfection: you intercept the size of a `std::array`, that is a `std::size_t`, so an unsigned integer, as an `int`, a signed integer.

If you write the partial specialization intercepting a value of the correct type, `std::size_t`,

```
// ..................VVVVVVVVVVV  (not int)
template<typename T, std::size_t N> 
struct make_it<std::array<T, N>, std::enable_if_t<(N > 4)>>
{
    static std::array<T, N> apply()
    {
        return std::array<T,N>{};  
    }
};
```

or also as `auto`, if you can use C++17,

```
// ..................VVVV
template<typename T, auto N> 
struct make_it<std::array<T, N>, std::enable_if_t<(N > 4)>>
{
    static std::array<T, N> apply()
    {
        return std::array<T,N>{};  
    }
};
```

you can see that your code compile with both compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Your template type doesn't match the type of array (`int` versus `std::size_t`).

As alternative, as you use C++17, you might use:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N> 
struct make_it<std::array<T, N>>
{
    static_assert(N >= 3); // As you don't provide specialization for those cases.

    static std::array<T, N> apply()
    {
        if constexpr(N == 3) {
            return {{T(0), T(0), T(0)}};
        } else if constexpr(N == 4) {
            return {{T(0), T(0), T(0), T(0)}};
        } else if constexpr(N > 4) {
            return {};
        }
    }
};
```